# Display TbDetailView attributes in a single table row

Tags: yii

```
<?php 

$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView',array(
    'type'=>'table condensed bordered',
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'regid',
        'fname',
         'lname',
        'mname',
        'registered_date',

    )
));

?>
```

For the above TbDetailView attributes, I want to display fname and lname in a single row.

Comment: That you can achieve by using `TbGridView`. Why you want to do it in `TbDetailsView`? any reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this approach:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView',array(
    'type'=>'table condensed bordered',
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'regid',
        array(
            'label'=>'User name',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>$model->fname.'&nbsp;'.$model->lname
        )
        'mname',
        'registered_date',
    )
));
```

Comment: @Manoj is this approach work? Why don't you mark answer as `resolved`?!